Laggy/Glitchy CSS Animations only on Firefox with Intersection Observer
I'm utilizing Intersection Observer API to hide the website header logo when it's not over (or close to being over) a background image.
Works well on Google Chrome, other chromium browsers and Safari (at the least mobile version) but the CSS animations play extremely laggy and sometimes delayed on Firefox. In fact sometimes it doesn't even trigger, it just freezes.
The CSS animations display fine when it's not triggered by Intersection Observer adding a class. (i.e.: the blue box in the example below has the fade-in class by default and the animation plays smoothly when you refresh the page and it fades in.)
I'm using Firefox 132.0.1 (64-bit).
I've asked others to test the website and the results were the same across.
Here is a sample page I made replicating the issue with a blue square as the header logo and red rectangle as the background image region:


const header = document.getElementById("headerhide");
const region = document.querySelector(".header-background");

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  header.classList.toggle("fade-out", !entry.isIntersecting);
  header.classList.toggle("fade-in", entry.isIntersecting);

}, {
  threshold: 0.2,
})
observer.observe(region)
.header-background {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.logo.logo-container {
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="headerhide" id="headerhide">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-background" id="region"></div>
</div>



(edit: also on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ob2t6wn3/3/)
(the CSS and js is normally in different files but for the example's sake I put them all in the html)
My specs (although I've tested on different devices and the issue persisted.)
OS: Windows 11 Home [64-bit]
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
Memory: 16GB
Motherboard: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-
Things I've tried:

Checking if it's a Firefox settings issue, I ruled out the privacy.fingerprintingProtection flag in about:config and Firefox Sync because disabling either or both did not solve the issue. I couldn't think of any other setting that could be causing this.

Adding will-change: opacity; to the CSS class, didn't work.

Adding a slight transform animation to trigger hardware acceleration but didn't work, adding a translateZ(0) also didn't work.

Adding debounce to the JavaScript function didn't work (although I'm not entirely sure if I did it correctly, I've started learning JavaScript 3 days ago.)

Using 2 observers to toggle the different classes, didn't work.

Trying on a fresh Firefox install (Developer Edition).

I tried using CSS transitions instead of keyframes but that didn't fix it either.



It might help also posting your hardware specs. If possible, test on a stock Firefox install to rule out any non-default setting you may have set. Alternatively, if you cannot reset Firefox to its default state, install Firefox Developer Edition (essentially a separate install of Firefox), keep it at stock settings, and test there.

I just tested on Firefox Developer Edition and the issue persists.
I will edit my specs into the original post in a second but as I said, I tested on different devices with different specs and the result was the same.

I've run your snippet on an Edge/Chrome and on Firefox (all on Windows 11) and the result on scrolling looks the same.

I'm experiencing the same issue on Firefox v120.0, macOS 14.6.1. Works fine in Chrome v130.0

I've managed to make it work on my end using the code below.
I remove the positioning-values (top, position: fixed etc.) and applied them to the element being observed instead - #headerhide.
I cannot give you a thorough explanation as to why this works, but I'm assuming it's either because #headerhide before served as an empty container with a height of 0, because its only child element had position: fixed, or because the animation now runs directly on the element that is visible.
But the above is just guesswork.


const header = document.getElementById("headerhide");
const region = document.querySelector(".header-background");

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  header.classList.toggle("fade-out", !entry.isIntersecting);
  header.classList.toggle("fade-in", entry.isIntersecting);

}, {
  threshold: 0.2,
})
observer.observe(region)
.header-background {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

#headerhide {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 2%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  position: fixed;
}

.logo-container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo.logo-container {
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="headerhide" id="headerhide">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-background" id="region"></div>
</div>




Yeah they probably throttle animations on elements that aren't on screen. Since the logo-container is fixed, it's probably escaping the "is in screen" check. Setting the animation on the logo-container also works (and is probably cleaner)

This works! I set it up so it observes and adds the class to the logo-container and the animations are smooth now. thank you!
Also i think the reason why the animations worked smoothly before I started using Intersection Observer is because I added the headerhide div while trying to figure out how to use the observer.
